# Title and all <head> content in <body>

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

This is the structure of the views folder:

```
/layout
    header.blade.php
    footer.blade.php
    template.blade.php

index.blade.php
```

header content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('img/favicon.png') }}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{ asset('img/favicon.png') }}">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
```

footer:

```
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
    @stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

template:

```
@include('layout.header')
@yield('content')
@include('layout.footer')
```

index:

```
@extends('layout.template')
@section('title', 'Title')
@section('content')
    <div>Content</div>
@endsection
```

When I inspect the html that's how the structure looks like:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <link rel="icon" href="http://localhost/project/public/img/favicon.png">
    <title>testing</title>
    <div>Test</div>
    <script src="http://localhost/project/public/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/project/public/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This causes the `favicon` not to be displayed.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: And do you close your title `@section` with `@endsection`?

Comment: @IbrahimHammed `Cannot end a section without first starting one`

Comment: Also tried `@section('title')
Title
@endsection` and still the same issue

Comment: Put your `header` and `footer` in a single file, then `yield(whatever needed anywhere)`, then `extend` it in each file.

Answer (score 0):

You are making this much more complicated then it needs to be. You can use the @extend method to use a template file. I would make it like this:

/layouts/app.blade.php

index.blade.php

```html
<!-- app.blade.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('img/favicon.png') }}">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{ asset('img/favicon.png') }}">
      <title>@yield('title', 'Title')</title>
   </head>
   <body>

      @yield('content')

      <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js') }}"></script>
      <script src="{{ asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- index.blade.php -->
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title, 'My Page Title')

@section('content')
  <div>
    <!-- Go crazy -->
    <!-- Everything in here will take place of the @yield('content') area -->
    <!-- in the app.blade.php file -->
  </div>
@endsection
```